# Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalBroadcastManager'

Tags: android, libraries

I followed a Youtube-Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8R2C86BIUc&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2) and in the last step the tutor was using a class called `LocalBroadcastManager`. But this class isn't supported anymore.. (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager) and Android Studio won't compile because of this class/error.
As far as i understand -i am new to Android Studio/Java- there is a option to migrate the project to androidx-libraries to get the code running but i have no clue how.

If i'm asking a absolutly beginner question, please give me a hint where i can get basic information to solve my problem.
Also Android Studio is changing/developing very fast, so that the solutions out there are not up to date anymore as far as i know.

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow but i cant figure out where to put what because im a absolute beginner.

### build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.btytcodingwithmitch"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
    }
```

### BluetoothConnectionServer.java:

```
package com.example.btytcodingwithmitch;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothConnectionService {

  ...

   private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;


        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //buffer store for stream

            int bytes; //bytes returned from read

            while (true){
                //read from Input Stream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream" + incomingMessage);

                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incoming Message");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage", incomingMessage);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading inputstream" + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error-Message**:

> "error: cannot find symbol variable LocalBroadcastManager"

Comment: It only available in android component class

Comment: And how can i add this class/library to my project?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this to your `app/build.gradle` file, inside `dependencies`:

`implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'`

Then **Rebuild Project**

This should work

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. If anyone else have the same problem you have to put " implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0' " under dependencies.

Comment: Yeah..also i forgot to mention the ``implementation`` part

Comment: Thanks, It's working. Actually this should be added into androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0 library by default, Why in AndroidX a special dependency for localbroadcastmanager.

Comment: @KapitaenWurst still have a same issue

Comment: This worked for me after looking for like 10 hours!!